# update view to a location from onChangeListener

Tags: android, location

I am following an Android weather app tutorial where the weather app requests a wether information about a place using an API;
However, the app was not "location aware" so I decided to try to do that, but when my app is created it calls the API with the hardcoded coordinates (private latitude and longitude). I dont understand why thid is happening, I am calling the getLoation method before the getForecast method. getLocation method should use the location manager's internet provider and set the latitude and longitude before the getForecast in called (which uses the coordinates to make the asynchronous API call). The strange thing is that when I press the refresh button, the location's coordinates are obtained from the location manager and the getLocationName is working fine too (finds the name of the location using the coordinates and set's the locationLabel to the name).

I suspect e problem is because if the fact that OkHTTP API that I am using to make the asynchronous call uses worker thread.

NODE: I am using Butter knife and YoYo API's also I have four classes which store the information about the weather called Forecast, Hour and Current and Day. I did not include them because I thought it is not important, since the problem is in my main activity class

Here is the code in my main activity class:

```
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Forecast mForecast;
//default coordinates - Aberdeen, UK Lati:57.156866 ; Long:
private double latitude = 57.156866;
private double longitude = -2.094278;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@InjectView(R.id.timeLabel) TextView mTimeLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.temperatureLabel) TextView mTemperatureLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.humidityValue) TextView mHumidityValue;
@InjectView(R.id.precipValue) TextView mPrecipValue;
@InjectView(R.id.summaryLabel) TextView mSummaryLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.locationLabel) TextView mLocationLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.windSpeedValue) TextView mWindSpeedValue;
@InjectView(R.id.iconImageView) ImageView mIconImageView;
@InjectView(R.id.refreshImageView) ImageView mRefreshImaveView;
@InjectView(R.id.progressBar) ProgressBar mProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mRefreshImaveView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getLocation();
            getForecast(latitude, longitude);
        }
    });
    getLocation();
    getForecast(latitude, longitude);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getForecast(latitude, longitude);
}

private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
    //animations
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1800).playOn(mLocationLabel);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1600).playOn(mTemperatureLabel);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1800).playOn(mIconImageView);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1000).playOn(mSummaryLabel);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1200).playOn(mHumidityValue);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1400).playOn(mWindSpeedValue);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1200).playOn(mPrecipValue);
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1200).playOn(mTimeLabel);

    String API_KEY = "API_KEY";
    String forecast = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+ API_KEY +"/"+ latitude+","+ longitude+"?units=auto";

    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        toggleRefresh();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecast)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                alertUserAboutError();
            }
            //when the call to the Okhttp library finishes, than calls this method:
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    //Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                       mForecast = parseForecastDetails(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateDisplay();
                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        //Toast.makeText(this,getString(R.string.network_unavailable_message),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        WIFIDialogFragment dialog = new WIFIDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.error_dialog_text));
    }
}

private void toggleRefresh() {
    if(mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRefreshImaveView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRefreshImaveView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
//updates the dysplay with the data in the CUrrentWeather locaal object
private void updateDisplay() {
    Current current = mForecast.getCurrent();
    //setting the current weather details to the ui
    mTemperatureLabel.setText(current.getTemperature()+"");
    mTimeLabel.setText("At "+ current.getFormattedTime()+" it will be");
    mHumidityValue.setText(current.getHumidity() +"%");
    mPrecipValue.setText(current.getPrecipChange()+"%");
    mSummaryLabel.setText(current.getSummery());
    mWindSpeedValue.setText(current.getWindSpeed()+"");
    mLocationLabel.setText(current.getTimeZone());
    //sets the mLocationLavel to the appropriate name and not the timezome from the  API
    getLocationName();
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, current.getIconId());
    mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);


}

private Forecast parseForecastDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    Forecast forecast = new Forecast();
    forecast.setCurrent(getCurrentDetails(jsonData));
    forecast.setHourlyForecast(getHourlyForecast(jsonData));
    forecast.setDailyForecast(getDailyForecast(jsonData));

    return forecast;
}

private Day[] getDailyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    JSONObject daily = forecast.getJSONObject("daily");
    JSONArray data = daily.getJSONArray("data");

    Day[] days = new Day[data.length()];

    for(int i = 0;i < data.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonDay = data.getJSONObject(i);
        Day day = new Day();

        day.setSummary(jsonDay.getString("summary"));
        day.setIcon(jsonDay.getString("icon"));
        day.setTemperatureMax(jsonDay.getDouble("temperatureMax"));
        day.setTime(jsonDay.getLong("time"));
        day.setTimezone(timezone);

        days[i] = day;

        Log.v(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),days[i].getIcon());
    }

    return days;
}

private Hour[] getHourlyForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    JSONObject hourly = forecast.getJSONObject("hourly");
    JSONArray data = hourly.getJSONArray("data");

    Hour[]hours = new Hour[data.length()];

    for(int i = 0;i < data.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonHour = data.getJSONObject(i);
        Hour hour = new Hour();

        hour.setSummary(jsonHour.getString("summary"));
        hour.setTemperature(jsonHour.getDouble("temperature"));
        hour.setIcon(jsonHour.getString("icon"));
        hour.setTime(jsonHour.getLong("time"));
        hour.setTimezone(timezone);

        hours[i] = hour;
    }

    return hours;
}

/*
 * throws JSONException, doing it like that, we place the
 * responsability of handaling this exeption to the caller of the method
*/
private Current getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    Log.i(TAG,"From JSON: " + timezone);

    JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
    Current mCurrent = new Current();
    mCurrent.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
    mCurrent.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
    mCurrent.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
    mCurrent.setPrecipChange(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
    mCurrent.setSummery(currently.getString("summary"));
    mCurrent.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
    mCurrent.setTimeZone(timezone);
    mCurrent.setWindSpeed(currently.getDouble("windSpeed"));

    Log.d(TAG, mCurrent.getFormattedTime());
    return mCurrent;
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    //contition to check if there is a network and if the device is connected
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        isAvailable = true;
    }

    return isAvailable;
}

private void alertUserAboutError() {
    AlertDIalogFragment dialog = new AlertDIalogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),getString(R.string.error_dialog_text));
}
private void getLocation(){

locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if(isNetworkAvailable()){
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1000, new MyLocationListener());
}else{
    WIFIDialogFragment dialog = new WIFIDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.error_dialog_text));
}
```

}
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                        + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}

private void getLocationName(){
    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addressList = geo.getFromLocation(this.latitude,this.longitude,1);
        if (addressList.isEmpty()){
            //gets the default name from the timeZone
            //that we set in as a local variable
        }else{
            if(addressList.size() > 0){
                Log.v(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),addressList.get(0).getLocality() + ", "+ addressList.get(0).getCountryName()+"");
                mLocationLabel.setText(addressList.get(0).getLocality() + ", "+ addressList.get(0).getCountryName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the app:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code, there are couple of things which are wrong.

1. you have called getLocation Method in OnCreate and onResume as well which is logically incorrect. you can keep it at onResume only if you wish you get location frequently.
2. when we call getLocation method it's not guarantee to give the latitude and longitude straight away, it takes it's own sweet time depending on the providers (Read API of location manager) hence your first call for getForecast will probably fail.
3. Solution : you can call getForecast method when onLocationChange method is called, by that time you can show progressDialog.
4. Make sure you have given Location related permissions in the manifest file

Comment: Thank you for your help and advise! I will definitely try to do these changes! :)

Comment: I have tried the suggestions that you made and now the app is getting the location as planned! Thank you so much! :)